# Amazon EC2, WOWZA not responding on port 8086

Tags: port, wowza

I have Amazon EC2 m1.medium instance running. I have download key pair (.pem) file and am able to connect via Putty.
After accessing console (via Putty) I use
sudo -s command for root access otherwise console prompt "Permission Denied".
Now WOWZA has been installed and running but WOWZA does not respond on 8086 port. I have my own security group and port 8086 open.
WOWZA should respond here http: / / IP:8086/   (I have elastic IP).
I have WOWZA running on t1.micro instance but now I need WOWZA on m1.medium instance.
When I connect via Flash I get error -->NetConnection.Connect.Failed (undefined)
Please help me out. IS this problem of installing wowza as a Sudo - s ?
                                       Thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually you had to paste wowza startup log here.
IMO you probably didn't start it.

Comment: Buddy that all log are fine I checked that.. no error. Even request is not going to WOWZA server. Is it because I been login as sudo -s ? and installed WOWZA ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the InBound Rules defined on your firewall security.

Goto Windows Firewall and Security Settings.
Check the Port open for 8086, if not add custom rule with reference to InBound Rule->Custom and add the specific port i.e.8086. Complete the wizard and then restart the wowza server.